# Why I'm getting four hard drives?

Tags: macos, recovery-hd

I have one HD, after some issues I reinstalled macOS, now I'm getting this,

Can I format/delete them?

[image: the 4 drives are below]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your internal SSD is formatted to APFS. This means your SSD contains two partitions in the default partition scheme:

- EFI
- APFS container

The APFS container itself contains four logical drives (volumes) - some of them with a specific role:

- Preboot
- Macintosh HD (your main volume with the system files and your data/apps)
- Recovery (recovery system)
- VM (virtual memory)

In the default scheme the four volumes share the whole space of the container - the reason why all show 250.79 GB in your screenshot.

In fact each volume is smaller but may be expanded dynamically.

You can get their real sizes by entering `diskutil ap list` in Terminal.app.

---

At least three of the four volumes are required to boot/run your Mac. The Recovery volume isn't really needed if your main volume **isn't** encrypted - but it's recommended to keep it.

**So don't delete them! Or only delete them if you have a known good backup of your Mac!**

Comment: thank you very much, I really need a clean install of this, so Im now backup my files, my only question is, Its will be possible to delete all these volumes and use just one while Im formating and Installing the OS

Thank you very much

Comment: @Cheerio In my understanding a "clean" install is a fresh system without any user data. The new default partition/logical volume scheme (=APFS) for Macs with an SSD is the one you see in your screenshot. It's **not** recommended to use an older, deprecated scheme (except some special reason exists e.g. an app incompatibility with APFS). You will end up with the exactly same scheme as visible above if you  do a "clean" install of High Sierra)!

Comment: Im very surprised by this massive knowledge, thank you very much, you made my day